# Colloborative programming with compiler

Tags: google-docs, collaborative

Does anyone know of any software like Google Docs, or collabedit that allows you to edit realtime collaboratively and even compile a .cpp or other program over the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of this website that will compile the code for you:
http://ideone.com/

Unfortunately, I cannot help in the real time editing front.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used this website, but seems like http://codebunk.com/ does the job.
It doesn't work for Java though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little webapp that does exactly that, i.e. it lets you compile Google Docs documents: http://compiler.m01.eu

You can write C++ code into a Google Document (and do that collaboratively if you like), and then click on a bookmark (provided on the site) to compile your code, which will either start the download of your binary or show a compiler error message.